# Programmatically Adding Labels To Newly Created Row?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm adding rows in the following manner:

```
Table.RowCount = Table.RowCount ++;
Table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.AutoSize));
```

How can I add a Label to each cell in this newly created row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [TableLayoutControlCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a%28VS.90%29.aspx).  There's an overload that allows you to specify the row and column where the new Label will be added.

This snippet adds a row to a TLP and then adds a new  Label to the first column of this new row:

```
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = "MyNewLabel";
    label.Text = "Added in my test";
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1);
```

Comment: How can I name the label when adding it?

Comment: @Soo: Yes you can.  I restructured the code so it's a little clearer how the Label is created.

Comment: I'm using the following code, but the cells don't autosize around the labels... tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.AutoSize));

Comment: @Soo:  hmmm. I couldn't get it to use an AutoSize SizeType on RowStyles on programmatically added rows either.  I [researched it a bit](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/122017/tablelayoutpanel-rows-and-rowstyles-do-not-correspond and I wonder it it's a bug.

Comment: Jay, the only other solution I can think of is have a BUNCH of rows set up with labels, and programmatically delete the ones I don't need.  Obviously this will take a lot of work, and will be limited by the number of rows I originally put in, but I can't really think of anything else.  Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a label, by default it's not autosize, I tried it just today.  Set the AutoSize property on the label to true and you might have more luck.